# Push notifications quotas in GCM and APNS

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating a mass marketing application where I can send coupons to all of my subscriber base which can be a few millions people and I should be able to send coupons through out the day as many times I want.

So,my confusion is will my mission be hindered by any kind of quotas like amount of push notifications in a day/week/month on these popular services.Also,is there any possibility of my app getting banned for sending so many messages to people.

My app won't spam the user with irrelevant stuff and the app will ensure that all the coupons sent,will be of interest to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Apple and Google don't publish any quotas of the number of messages you can send in a period of time.

Apple has some reference to the throughput in a [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG44) :

> **There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs**. The iOS 6.1
>   press release stated that APNs has sent over 4 trillion push
>   notifications since it was established. It was announced at WWDC 2012
>   that APNs is sending 7 billion notifications daily.
>
> If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second,
>   your server might benefit from improved error handling logic.

Based on that quote, if you are sending 9,000 push notifications per second or less, you are good. However, this is not an upper limit, just an example of a rate you should be able to achieve. They actually claim there are no limits.

Google make the same claim about [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) :

> GCM is completely free **no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there are no quotas**.