# Getting GCM registration response "User Registration Limit Exceeded" for some requests

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, instanceid

**We have an Android app that registers with GCM using Instance ID API.**

Unfortunately, the GCM statistics in the Google Play Developer Console show that some registration attempts are apparently answered with the response code **"HTTP 200 - User Registration Limit Exceeded"**.

[image: GCM registrations by GCM response code graph]
[image: GCM registration response codes pie chart]

**It is just 0.01%, but we would still like to know, why and when this happens and what we can do about it.**

I didn't find any information about a "User Registration Limit". There seem to be or [there seem to was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053367/push-notifications-quotas-in-gcm-and-apns) a [limit for sending notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit), but what about registrations?

**Is there any quota on GCM registrations using Instance ID API?**

The registration is implemented according to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), so we are basically calling [`instanceID.getToken`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID.html#getToken(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)) on each app start like this:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Comment: i don't think there is a limit on registrations, could this not be that the user is some how registering in quick succession  which then causes the error and they get blocked for a certain time. I had instances where by you could completely close the app and reopen and if you did it multiple times the GCM would block the reg for a while. just a thought

Comment: Good point, @Rob85. Maybe the app is crashing in some rare cases and affected users are restarting the app over and over again then, which leads to that response... I guess we can just try to repoduce it this way and see if we get that response code.

Comment: Yes for sure , it makes more sense otherwise if you had reached some sort of limit then everyone who registered after that limit is reached would have the same response. I only had this same sort of thing yesterday when i was testing so i will see if i can reproduce and grab the error :-)

Comment: It's been too long. Is there a chance you found the reason for this error message?

Comment: Any update on this issue?